# Detect when a row is edited in a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I've been trying to google this but have been unable to find a solution that works for me.

I have a DataGrid that is displaying some info from a SQL table that the client dosn't know about. 
The client just sends a request to the server and gets a List<SomeClass> as a response that it then displays in a DataGrid.

I need to detect when the user makes change to a row and I need the new values that the user entered.
Currently I'm using RowEditEnding event. And the method that handles this event can then:

```
private void editRowEventHandler(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    SomeClass sClass = e.Row.DataContext as SomeClass;
    // Send sClass to the server to be saved in the database...
}
```

This gives me the row that was being edited. But it gives me the row before the changes, and I'm unable to figure out how to get the row after the changes happen.

Is there anyone here that knows how I can do this or can point me in a direction where I might be able to find out?

Comment: Why not just catch it in the set of SomeClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you are trying to detect the change in object. It comes down to the properties of the SomeClass, thus you need to focus on "Cell" instead of "Row"

Assuming your datagrid is resultGrid, i come up with the below code:

```
resultGrid.CellEditEnding += resultGrid_CellEditEnding;
void resultGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            var yourClassInstance = e.EditingElement.DataContext;
            var editingTextBox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
            var newValue = editingTextBox.Text;
        }
```

the "e" also contains information about Row and Column of the Cell. Thus you will know which editor the cell is using. In this case, i assume that it is a textbox.
Hope it help.

Comment: Was hoping that I could just get the row, with the new values, with just one line. Because I have a class with 20 member variables. So I guess I'll have to write a switch to see what column I'm working with and assign the value to the correct member variable.
It's more code than I wanted to write, but it does solve the problem, thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

See the discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/d9afc793-ec66-428f-a087-bccbbcffda73), to avoid reading out cell-by-cell.

```
private void OnRowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit) {
        ListCollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource) as ListCollectionView;
        if (view.IsAddingNew || view.IsEditingItem) {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new DispatcherOperationCallback(param => 
            { 
                // This callback will be called after the CollectionView
                // has pushed the changes back to the DataGrid.ItemSource.

                // Write code here to save the data to the database.
                return null; 
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { null });
        }
    }
}
```